# D3 disable pan & zoom when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've rendered a d3 map that has pan and zoom enabled, but when scrolling down the viewport either on desktop or mobile, the window gets stuck zooming in the map.

Is there a way to temporarily disable d3.zoom, while the window is scrolling?

I've seen ways of toggling the zoom/pan using a button as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/0xncswrk/, but I wanted to know if it's possible without having to add a button.  Here's my current zoom logic.

Thanks!

```
this.zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on('zoom', () => {
    this.svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
  });

this.svg = d3.select(this.el).append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', this.height)
    .attr('class', 'bubble-map__svg-us')
    .call(this.zoom)
    .append('g');
```

Comment: Zoom and scrolling use share the same gestures - how to distinguish them? How can you decide if a mousewheel‘s meant to scroll or zoom?

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Wow old answer but never saw your comment. Sorry about that. Yeah sorry I forgot to consider mobile zooming.

In the documentation, perhaps this is new, but they recommend having more granular control of what zoom you allow by using [zoom.filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filterhttps://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filter). For touch related events, they also support [zoom.touchable](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_touchable).

As specified in the [`d3-zoom`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom) documentation

> To disable just wheel-driven zooming (say to not interfere with native scrolling), you can remove the zoom behavior’s wheel event listener after applying the zoom behavior to the selection:
>
> selection
>       .call(zoom)
>       .on("wheel.zoom", null);

You can also consider just setting the `scaleExtent` to be `[1,1]` especially if it's just temporary so it locks the zoom to only one possible scale but preferably you opt for what the documentation says :P

Comment: That would disable the wheel zoom, but pinch-zoom, drag on mobile/tablet.  I poked around the docs and didn't see any events for that.

Also, would the idea be to set the wheel.zoom to null while the user is scrolling the window and to re-enable it when they stop scrolling the window?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams hey sorry I never saw your comment >< I updated my answer although you probably were right that back then perhaps d3-zoom didn't support those things or at least it wasn't clear in the documentation. Now there are some new things available so I added those to this answer. Hope they help!

Comment: @aug this worked for me, BTW how can i scroll up and down on mouse wheel event?

Answer (score 0):

Got here because I was dealing with a similar problem. Perhaps for anyone coming after this, a simple way to deal with this might be to use the `filter()` method that a `zoom()` instance provides. That will allow you to toggle between applying or ignoring zoom events altogether. It works a little better than temporarily setting `null` to watchers because - at least in my experience - the events then still get recorded and stacked. As a consequence, you would zoom in or out in unexpected leaps once you re-enabled the handler. The filter actually really ignores what's going on, it seems. To implement:

```
let isZooming = true; // Use controls to set to true or false

zoom()
    // Make sure we only apply zoom events if zooming is enabled by the user
    .filter(() => isZooming)
    .on('zoom', event => {
      // Specify whatever you want to do with the event
    });
```

Doc: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filter