# Can't touch scroll vertically on mobile on D3 SVG with d3-zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have a d3 graph with an SVG enabled with `d3-zoom`. Simply put, I have configured zoom to allow the user to pan (and only pan) on the x axis (and only the x axis):

```js
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 1]) // scale 1x to 1x (no zooming)
  .translateExtent([[
      xExtent,
      0
  ], [
      // Bottom right extent: [center of last age, graph height]
     rightExtent,
      graphHeight
  ]])
  .on('zoom', this.zoom)
  .on('start', this.zoomStart)
  .on('end', this.zoomEnd)
  
svg.call(zoom)
  .on('wheel.zoom', null);
```

This has worked so far and allows the user to pan around the X-axis on both mobile and desktop devices.

The problem is, on iOS and Android, when touching the graph to scroll down on the page, the page remains in place - the scroll events are somehow being intercepted by `d3-zoom`.

I have looked all over the d3-zoom docs and have not found anything except this statement: `"If the user tries to zoom by wheeling when already at the corresponding limit of the scale extent, the wheel events will be ignored and not initiate a zoom gesture. This allows the user to scroll down past a zoomable area after zooming in, or to scroll up after zooming out."`. My problem is that I am still having an issue on mobile devices scrolling past the graph.

I have also scoured SO and discovered this question, with a partial answer that is incomplete to what I need: [D3 disable pan & zoom when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081317/d3-disable-pan-zoom-when-scrolling)

How can I use zoom on my SVG while also being able to scroll on mobile devices? If needed I am willing to completely disable "vertical" panning on the SVG if that is possible with d3, I just need to be able to scroll the page while also panning to the right and left on the X axis.

### Update with REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

I believe this occurs with any instance of `d3-zoom` and panning. Here is a very simple example with editable code: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom

If you open the example on a mobile device (e.g. iPhone Safari), you will see once you get down to the graph, you cannot scroll the page down with touch unless you manage to scroll on the edge of the page where d3 is not active.

Let me know if I can provide any more clarification.

Comment: Sadly I am unable to use the snippet that you have in your answer, could you maybe rewrite it? Right now it's not plotting anything, and in the console there are errors regarding missing libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AlejandroVales – I have added a reproducible example. I believe this occurs on any graph with d3-zoom.

Comment: I'm using comment because I don't have a complete answer or time to research one, but I've seen this behavior plenty. I believe that you need to use pointer-events in SVG to get the same behavior you get from DOM objects, but you may have to disable x-axis scrolling or only allow it when in a 'zoomed' mode.

Comment: @element119 have you resolved the problem?